# Count of repeated column values in Sybase

Tags: sql, relational-database, sap-ase

I have a requirement wherein I have to find how many times a particular column has repeated. For Example:

```
Col1 | Col2
------------
1    |2
2    |2
3    |3
4    |3
5    |3
```

in the above table, value '2' in the column is repeated twice and value '3' is repeated thrice. I want to know a way to find this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yous should use `group by` clause as below

```
select col2, count(col2)
from tab
group by col2
```